# Blurry / Corrupted  Google Maps Controls

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am seeing some really odd behaviour on my Google Maps app. I am using Backbone:

```
  initialize: ->
    osmMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(
      getTileUrl: (coord, zoom) ->
        "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/#{zoom}/#{coord.x}/#{coord.y}.png"
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
      isPng: true
      alt: "OpenStreetMap layer"
      name: "OSM"
      maxZoom: 19
    )

    cloudMadeMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType(
      getTileUrl: (coord, zoom) ->
        "http://b.tile.cloudmade.com/a97cc0871d97477b911c3f9155a93ee7/26250/256/#{zoom}/#{coord.x}/#{coord.y}.png"
      tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
      isPng: true
      alt: "CloudMade layer"
      name: "CMade"
      maxZoom: 13
    )

    lat = 51.503
    lng = -0.113
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
    options =
      zoom: 10
      center: latlng
      mapTypeId: 'OSM'
    @gMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options)
    @gMap.mapTypes.set('OSM', osmMapType)
    @gMap.mapTypes.set('CloudMade', cloudMadeMapType)
    @gMap.setMapTypeId(google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN)
```

I am loading the API as such:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But for some reason... the google maps controls and overlays are "blurry":

[blurry controls... http://vuknikolic.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/twitter-bootstrap-and-google-maps-v3/](http://vuknikolic.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/twitter-bootstrap-and-google-maps-v3/)

and an infowindow...

[image: infowindow doing the same thing]

I have looked over and over the code and can not see the error, there are no errors in console either.

---

@geocodezip was right, it was the css. Essentially Google Maps does not like the way BootStrap handels the max-width of images. So you need to put a little hack in your CSS...

```
#map img {
    max-width: none;
}
```

http://vuknikolic.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/twitter-bootstrap-and-google-maps-v3/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no errors in your code.  It is a problem with your css.

Just add this CSS in your map container (assuming it has `id=gmap`):

```
#gmap img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: aha! it seems to be Twitter Bootstrap! Great spot - now why on earth would BootStrap cause that?

Comment: http://vuknikolic.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/twitter-bootstrap-and-google-maps-v3/ found a fix - thanks! I think that was a case of staring at the wrong code for tooooo long!

Comment: yep thanks - sorry I just answered it with more detail as it was a specific BootStrap error and thought it might be helpful to someone in the future! Thanks for pointing out the CSS error! Should have looked there sooner!

Comment: You've saved me a LOT of headache. Thank you!

Comment: This is the only solution.. Good one.. I came here late but its great.