# Google Maps is showing some misbehavior

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'v managed to implement the Google Maps Api which shows multiple marker, but the Maps Div is always showing some misbehavior like in the picture below (shadow is incorrect, there is a wave (?!) under the "vienna" title, and on the left side the control-buttons are missing).

[image: Google Maps Misbehavior]

I'm using chrome on mac, has restarted my mac a few times, and it is reproducible on firefox and safari.

My code looks like:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false"></script>
</head>

<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
                    var locations = [
                      ['Vienna',48.2144203,16.383573,1]
                      ['Test',48.53234,16.32367,2]
                    ];

                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                      zoom: 13,
                      center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.2144203,16.383573),
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    });

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    var marker, i;

                    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
                        map: map
                      });

                      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                        return function() {
                          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                          infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                      })(marker, i));
                    }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blurry / Corrupted  Google Maps Controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733761/blurry-corrupted-google-maps-controls)

Comment: wow perfect. yes i use bootstrap. that link (and the one line of code) helped me out! thanks. if you make that comment into an answer i would accept it! thanks

Comment: That isn't usable as answer, just upvote [that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733761/blurry-corrupted-google-maps-controls), this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

this problem commonly comes from bootstrap. just add inline style in your gmaps page with max-width:none; and it will be fixed.

```
<style>
       img {max-width: none !important;}
</style>
```

Comment: This might conflict with the map tiles. In my case, in iOS, the map wasn't rendering its tiles properly due to this max-width property set to none. But when i removed it, although the map was working fine but again those plus minus buttons disappeared. Not sure how to tackle this