# Bootstrap 3 and google maps 2

Tags: css, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-maps-api-2

I have a problem while working with Bootstrap 3 and gmaps 2..The problem is that my map controls are not displayed properly as shown in the image bellow..
[image]

Bellow is my code as well :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize(){
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
  {
    map=new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.084142,25.151997), 11);
    map.setUIToDefault();


  }

  }
  </script>
 </head>  
 <body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
```

Any ideas..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blurry / Corrupted  Google Maps Controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12733761/blurry-corrupted-google-maps-controls)

Comment: The [Google Maps API v2](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference.html) is deprecated (and turned off), it should not be used for new development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too once crossed this problem, this is **conflict** *occurred with your `CSS` with `gmaps`.*   You might have a global CSS like

```
img {
  max-width:100% // or something
}
```

By inspecting(using browser's dev tools) you can find where it is being overridden and try to make use of either `id` or `class` selectors and change it to **`none`**.

I have tested it [here](http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/examples/basic.html)

```
#map_canvas img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: I have not implemented this piece of code anywhere.Are you sure that this is the problem??

Comment: @John this is common, might be bootstrap.min.css or any other.  However this can be fixed easily by adding the css in the answer.  By inspecting your page you can easily find where it is getting overridden

Comment: It might be inside the bootstrap css code...Thank you very much for the reply.With #map_canvas img {
  max-width: none;
} it worked!!!

Comment: @John I'm glad I was able to help :)